# Spring Batch issue : "Problems occurred while synchronizing remote to local directory"

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-batch, spring-integration-sftp

We PUT file on some SFTP server and then run spring batch.when spring batch run below steps were executed.

1. pick file from FTP location
2. process the file.
3. delete file.

we are facing below exception while spring batch performing above steps.

```
ERROR org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler: 140 - org.springframework.integration.MessagingException: Problem occurred while synchronizing remote to local directory
            at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:189)
            at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.receive(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.java:162)
            at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:111)
            at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:184)
            at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:51)
            at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:143)
            at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:141)
            at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:273)
            at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:52)
            at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:48)
            at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:49)
            at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:268)
            at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:53)
            at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
            at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
            at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
        Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessagingException: Failed to execute on session
            at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:306)
            at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:163)
            ... 21 more
        Caused by: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to remove file: 2: Specified file path is invalid.
            at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.remove(SftpSession.java:83)
            at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.copyFileToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:230)
            at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.access$100(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:59)
            at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer$1.doInSession(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:172)
            at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer$1.doInSession(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:163)
            at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:297)
            ... 22 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a security issue - maybe you don't have delete permissions.

The exact same path is used for the fetch and when deleting (if configured to delete the remote file after retrieval). Clearly the fetch worked ok because we're now in the delete phase.

You should consult the server logs.

Comment: thanks for your answer.but we are not sure that these exception was occurred while spring-batch performed delete operation.so could you have any other suggestion to check it out.

Comment: The stack trace clearly shows it's spring integration having difficulty deleting the file from the remote server after downloading it. Spring Batch is not involved at that point.